# How to replace column values for cohort analysis

Tags: r, analysis

I am very new to using R. I have searched regarding this but couldn't find any pointers.

I am doing cohort analysis and the data under Month1 is the number of new users that signed up for in that particular month. Month2 is the number of users that continued from previous month's sign up.

I have a set of data as follows

```
Month_Start_Date   Month1   Month2   Month3  Month4   Month5   Month6
2010-01-01           10        12       11      9       3        15
2010-02-01           10         9       11      9       3        15
2010-03-01           10         9        7      9       3        15
2010-04-01           10         7        5      6       3        15
2010-05-01           10         8        6      3       4        15
```

I would like my data to be in the following format:

```
Month_Start_Date   Month1   Month2   Month3  Month4   Month5   Month6
2010-01-01           10         0       0       0       0        0
2010-02-01           10         9       0       0       0        0
2010-03-01           10         9       7       0       0        0
2010-04-01           10         7       5       6       0        0
2010-05-01           10         8       6       3       4        0
```

My main data has data from 2008. I am filtering to take only from 2010. Hence, I would want the Month2, Month3, Month4, Month5 as 0 for 2010-01-01 and Month3, Month4, Month5 as 0 for 2010-02-01

Comment: Possibly `df[-1][upper.tri(df[-1])] <- 0; df` where `df` is your data

Comment: @RichardScriven, I was just writing exactly the same comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you want `upper.tri` to set the values to zero.  Starting with

```
> df
#   Month_Start_Date Month1 Month2 Month3 Month4 Month5 Month6
# 1       2010-01-01     10     12     11      9      3     15
# 2       2010-02-01     10      9     11      9      3     15
# 3       2010-03-01     10      9      7      9      3     15
# 4       2010-04-01     10      7      5      6      3     15
# 5       2010-05-01     10      8      6      3      4     15
```

we can replace the upper triangle with zeros with

```
> df[-1][upper.tri(df[-1])] <- 0
> df
#   Month_Start_Date Month1 Month2 Month3 Month4 Month5 Month6
# 1       2010-01-01     10      0      0      0      0      0
# 2       2010-02-01     10      9      0      0      0      0
# 3       2010-03-01     10      9      7      0      0      0
# 4       2010-04-01     10      7      5      6      0      0
# 5       2010-05-01     10      8      6      3      4      0
```

Comment: WOW!! Thanks for the quick response. I have applied the same to my data but my data returned 0s from Month3 for the first row and 0s from Month4 for second row. Any tips on fixing this>

Comment: It is working to an extent. When I apply to my full data, it is returning 0s from Month3 for the first row and 0s from Month4 for second row. Any tips on fixing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might be best to show a few more rows of the data so that it's not a square matrix on the numeric columns, and the result from that

Comment: I was able to get in the format that I wanted :). I just removed the -1 and used this :df[][upper.tri(df[])] <- 0. Thanks a lot for the easy way out. I was thinking that it might involve some big looping!

Comment: I'm guessing this was a zoo object (which is really an index vector and an attached matrix) .... and you didn't tell us.